# cannot find package "google.golang.org/api/gensupport" in any of XXXX

Tags: go, google-translation-api

**GO version: 1.17.3**

**GO mod file included: NO**

I am using this package in my code to use google translation api. However when I go get the below package & run my code it says:

command:

```
go get "google.golang.org/api/option"
```

output:

```
cannot find package "google.golang.org/api/gensupport in any of GOPATH & GOROOT"
```

When I previously get it on other machine in July, it was working fine.

How can I solve this issue, since I am not using it directly in my code.

Comment: Couple of things to check - 1. What's the go version you're using? 2. Can you try `go get -u -v "google.golang.org/api/option"` 3. Does your project have a go module defined?

Comment: @KishoreBandi , -v flag gave me a hint. The error was not in this package but in other package wiich was dependent upon this. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Amandeepkaur, are you still facing the issue? If you have solved the issue, can you add the resolution steps as an answer to this question.